# Grouping tag in JSF not rendering anything?

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

Is there any tag in JSF which can be used to assign some id to group of child tags, but not rendering any content? Something like this:

```
<h:unknowntag id="group">
  <h:inputText id="name" value="#{bean.name}" required="true">
    <f:ajax event="blur" execute="name" render="group" />
  </h:inputText>
  <h:message for="name"/>
</h:unknowntag>
```

I don't need `<h:unknowntag>` to render any content, but I need it to set id to whole group which I want to rerender after ajax event. Is there such a tag in JSF 2.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `<h:panelGroup>` for this. It renders a `<span>`, but that does not harm since it has no special meaning in HTML markup. You need an element anyway since the `id` *has* to be put somewhere in HTML DOM so that JS/Ajax can locate it for re-render.